# Vue 3 - radio input not checked after click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some questions that are using radio buttons for the answers.
The problem is that after the click on an answer the clicked radio input will be not checked and I'm also unable to disable the others. I'm using Vue 3 for the front-end and nodejs for the back-end.
Is there any fix for this?

```html
      <div class="col-8 p-0 mx-auto" v-for="(item, index) in questions" :key="index">
        <div class="card text-dark bg-light mb-3">
          <div class="card-header">{{ index }}</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ item.question }}</h5>
            <div class="form-check" v-for="(choice, index) in item.choices" :key="index">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="index" :id="index" :value="index" v-model="answers" @click.prevent="updateAnswers(index)" >
              <label class="form-check-label" :for="index">{{ choice }}</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

my component js code:

```js
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data(){
    return {
      isLoading: true,
      questions: [],
      answers: []
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.init();
  },
  methods: {
    init(){
      axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8990/init'
      }).then( (res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        this.questions = res.data;
        console.log(this.questions);
        this.isLoading = false;
      });
    },
    updateAnswers(value){
// here I'm pushing the clicked radio value into answers array
    this.answers.push(value);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Are you able to push the values in answers array?

Comment: yes I don't have any problem with this. the only problem is with the radio that will be not checked.

Comment: Can you share a link to codepen or fiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of the problem is @click.prevent directive. You can use @change="updateAnswers(index)" instead of @click.prevent.

Comment: I will try change it and let you know. Anyway any suggestion on how to disable other options availavle?

Comment: I get `this.answers.push(index)` in my `updateAnswers()` method after changed the directive. This is starnge becuase the variable `answers` is an array

Comment: You can disable other options with :disabled="disabled == 1".

Comment: Unfortunately not work, radio input still unchecked and the `@change` will also cause problem with the `Array.push()` function. Also since I'm in a `v-for` loop I cant just set the `disabled` attribute into markup, it need to be added dynamically!

Comment: In my sample code, answers.push() works well. You can view it in my [codepen](https://codepen.io/khinmemelatt/pen/eYgxrJK).You can disable options depending on a value by using :disable or v-bind:disable.

Comment: I saw it but you didn't used `v-model`. If I remove v-model the code works fine but since I have a `v-for` all the radio generated will lost the check so I need a way to disable others options of the same rradio group and mantain the check of the one selected. I can't rely on a value because there are multiple choices that will differ

Comment: Although I add v-model in my codepen, the radio buttons work well.

Comment: The issue was related to the `name` attribute that wasn't unique and to the `v-model`, I was trying to use the same for all the radio inputs generated from the `v-for` loop. I've changed it to an unique name and removed the `v-model` and now works fine. Thank you for the help.